# Double click on LinkButton causes redirection to the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET WebForms (which I am not very familiar with) app. A certain page shows different content (included multiple editable grids) depending on how you accessed the page. The problem is people sometimes press the same button twice when the effect takes some time to be reflected on the page. Every time they press the button the app enters the Page_Load method and goes through this code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   ViewState["ViewForRefresh"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   Session["SessionForRefresh"] = ViewState["ViewForRefresh"].ToString();
}
else
{
   if (ViewState["ViewForRefresh"].ToString() != Session["SessionForRefresh"].ToString())
   {
      Page.Response.Redirect(currentPage, false);
   }
   Session["SessionForRefresh"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   ViewState["ViewForRefresh"] = Session["SessionForRefresh"].ToString();
}
```

On a single click, `ViewState["ViewForRefresh"]` and `Session["SessionForRefresh"]` are equal, but on a double click (or single click twice) they are not equal, I guess since the second click of the button would trigger an action with old data or something. Is it possible to somehow prevent this redirection action?

I have tried, so far, to disable the buttons after a click to prevent a double click:

```
var addFunciarBtn = (LinkButton)GridFunciarAreas.FooterRow.FindControl("addFunciarRow");
var addConstructionsBtn = (LinkButton)GridConstructions.FooterRow.FindControl("addConstructionsRow");
addFunciarBtn.Enabled = false;
addConstructionsBtn.Enabled = false;
```

This did not work. I can still double click the button. I also tried to return false on click: `addFunciarBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false");` to prevent a page refresh. Another thing I tried was add `CausesValidation="False"` to the aspx markup for the button. This did not have the required effect either.

What am I doing wrong (or misunderstanding) and is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the markup for the link button in the GridView, but with a post-back, then server-side code is "too late" to disable the button, since the browser "round trip" has to 100% complete before you going to see the results of the server-side code (and that includes the code to disable or hide the button).

In other words, the whole web page is sent to the server. On client side, they see the browser "spinner/wait" icon. During that time, if they click the button again, then of course the button will not have been disabled. So, trying to disable the button with server-side code to prevent the server-side code from running again? As noted, that's too late.

So, worse yet, is LinkButtons (a hyper link) don't really have much of a "disable" setting. So, what I would suggest is that you add a client side click event to the LinkButton, and hide the button, and that way it can't be clicked again until such time the browser page post back (round trip) is complete.

So, say this simple GridView with a link button:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="120px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdView" runat="server"
                                CssClass="btn myshadow"
                                OnClick="cmdView_Click"
                                OnClientClick="$(this).hide();"  >                
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> View
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelClickInfo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

So, note how we added a client side click event to the LinkButton (I used jQuery expression - so this assumes you have jQuery installed - and you likely do).

Thus, when we click the button, it will "hide" until such time that the browser page round trip will complete (and thus the button will re-show after that routine trip is complete).

So, code behind is thus this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();    
    }

    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        int PK = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        string sInfo = $@"Database PK = {PK} <br/>
                        Row index click = {gRow.RowIndex}<br/>
                        Hotel Name = {gRow.Cells[3].Text}";

        LabelClickInfo.Text = sInfo;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // fake 2 second processing dealy
    }
```

Note how the LinkButton click code gets the current row (NamingContainer).

And note how we for this demo "fake" a 2-second-long server delay.

So, when we run above the result is this:

[image]

So, to prevent a double click, we can't use or run code server side, since the code behind does not show any results until the browser "round trip" is 100% complete. In that wait time, the user can thus click the button "many" times, and all the server code in the world to hide or disable the button will not help, since that server-side code is far too late to disable the button.

And if during the "long time" the server code is running, if the user hits the button again, then a whole new page "round trip" is started, and the previous round tip is terminated. Thus, if we click on another button while waiting, then the effect is now this:

[image]

Now, in theory, the total time should have been 8 seconds. However, each time you click a button, the existing server-side code is terminated.

So, I suppose one might want to disable ALL of the buttons, but in most cases, giving feed back and hiding the current button click should suffice. However, as above shows, the only practical way to achieve this is to run client-side code first to hide or disable the button. Note how we don't have to re-show the button, since as noted, after a post-back, a whole brand-new fresh browser page is returned from the server.